# what does "domain" mean when referring to DDD

Tags: development-methodologies, domain-driven-design

What does the word domain mean regarding driven design/development?

Not in terms of semantics or a scholarly definition but in terms of how it modifies processes or philosophies?

I was reading a post: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57828/your-software-problem-solution-approach

I came across this buzzword, DDD, and didn't really know what that meant.

Comment: This is from the linked question : *DDD - Domain Driven Design*

Comment: Did you look up [domain driven design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_driven_design) in Wikipedia?

Comment: From Wikipedia:

Domain: A sphere of knowledge, influence, or activity. The subject area to which the user applies a program is the domain of the software.

Comment: What part of the wikipedia definition is incomplete or confusing?  Please be **specific** in your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Domain refers to the specific subject that the project is being developed for. Accounting is a common domain for DDD. The goal of DDD is to limit complexity of a solution by tailoring it as close as possible to the domain with the help of experts in that domain.

Comment: May I ask you a question? You said, "Accounting is a common domain for DDD". Accounting Domain contains Asset, Account Payable, Credit, Payroll, etc. what do domain experts call them? Are they Model, right?

Comment: @BunthaiDeng Just came across your comment. The term *domain experts* refers to people who work in accounting; they call these things "Asset, Account Payable, Credit, Payroll, etc.", not Model. A model is not a class or a component. The term *model* refers to how you think about all these aspects of accounting, and to how you ultimately choose to represent them in code. Your *notion* of what Accounting contains, how those things interrelate, and how you'll code them up *is the model*. Two different software dev teams will come up with different models of the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could also say that DOMAIN is where you code the business logic of your application.